# What are the differences between all the high end gears/blueprints vendors

Tags: the-division

I think there are 3 kinds of vendors who sell high end gears/blueprints in total:

- Base of Operations phoenix credit vendor
- Dark Zone credit vendor in DZ02 - DZ05
- Dark Zone phoenix credit vendor in DZ06

Which one gets you the strongest gears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Base of Operations Phoenix Vendor**

- some of the high-end items are level 31
- high-end blueprints do **not** require high-end Division Tech
- no DZ rank requirement

**Dark Zone credit vendor in DZ02 - DZ05**

- all high-end items are only level 30 (which makes them less useful than many level 31 purples)
- high-end blueprints **require high-end Division Tech** (which is extremely hard to come by)
- DZ rank 50 requirement

**Dark Zone phoenix credit vendor in DZ06**

- some of the high-end items are level 31
- high-end blueprints **require high-end Division Tech** (which is extremely hard to come by)
- DZ rank 50 requirement

**Base of Operations Advanced Weaponry Vendor**

- only high-end items are two unique (named) weapons [(currently Pakhan — an LMG, and Cassidy — a shotgun)](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BsJl8i67PMg/maxresdefault.jpg)
- uses regular credits, but it's almost Ɖ500K each

All things considered, as of now Base of Operation Phoenix vendor is the best option if you're looking for blueprints. If you're DZ rank 50, DZ06 is a good alternative for pre-made weapons and gear.

see also [What can high-end Division Tech be used for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260100/what-can-high-end-division-tech-be-used-for)

**UPDATE: [From patch 1.1 notes](http://blog.ubi.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-divisions-1-1-incursions-update/)**:

> - The vendor in the Church Safe House will now sell items in Dark Zone Funds instead of Phoenix Credits
> - Added new level 31 and 32 High-End items Blueprints to Vendors
> - Removed Division Tech requirements from some level 31 High-End Blueprints

This patch will be released April 12th, 2016.

Comment: I wonder how often the Base of Operations Advanced Weaponry changes.  It has been almost 2 weeks since this answer was posted, and the weapons (Pakhan and Cassidy) have not changed.

Comment: Seems that some high-end stuff never changes. AFAIK, blueprints don't change in any of the vendors.

Answer (score -1):

Phoenix Credits is the endgame currency as the game currently stands.

The base and the DZ06 vendor both sell the highest quality blue prints.
Its Yellow ilvl31 gear, which is the highest u can currently get.

For the recipes from the DZ u also requier Div Tech (yellow x3) to be able to craft it, so its highly sought after and in the next week or so more and more people will farm for it, since they crafted BiS gear from the outside vendor.

The recipes from the base for phoenix, just requiere the normal mats.

All the other DZ vendors sell you ilvl30 yellow gear, which imo you should never craft, since ilvl31 purples are usually better already...

To sum it all up, Phoenix Credits == endgame == strongest gear