# What can high-end Division Tech be used for?

Tags: the-division

Standard (green) Division Tech can be used for crafting Specialized (blue) ingredients.

Specialized (blue) Division Tech can be used for crafting High-end (gold) ingredients.

But what can High-end (gold) Division Tech be used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The high-end Division Tech is a requirement for crafting items which come from a recipe bought from a Dark Zone vendor.

Here is a screen capture of a Dark Zone recipe. Where you can see on the right that it requires high-end Division Tech as a crafting material.

[image: Dark zone recipe]

[Youtube.com - Guide To Maxing Out Character, Level 31 Items](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LngLYbAU3s8)

Comment: You can also create other yellow/gold resources with division tech, like tools, weapon parts etc. So some Kind of cross crafting the other parts. Personally ... better dont to that, because yellow Division tech is pretty rare.

Comment: That's what's so nice about "MMOs" and their devs' constant fiddling: this answer is *NOW* wrong since DZ vendors don't sell blueprints anymore.